# Sandboxing static fields

Tags: java, multithreading, static

I must use a numeric library whose code is generated from FORTRAN. Resulting code is very fast, but it is made of class with only `static` methods. The problem is that the methods have side effect (they change static fields), and thus not compatible with multithreading.

Is there a way to sandbox them ? (Each thread sees a different class)

PS: Changing the library is not an option, as the generated code is not human friendly. (in fact the original FORTRAN code is also not human friendly)

Answer (score 2):

I think you could simply remove all `static` keywords and the class name from before method invocations (if generated code qualifies static methods with class name) from the library sources. Both operations are simple find-and-replace and so you don't need to understand the generated code.

Then, each thread could have its own instance of library class.

If that's not an option, maybe you could provide each thread with its own custom ClassLoader, by using `Thread.setContextClassLoader()`. Each ClassLoader has separate class definitions, so in that way perhaps you could achieve the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of accessing the class directly, load it in a new `ClassLoader`, then invoke the method you're interested in by reflection. The changes to `static` fields will be reflected in the copy of the class in that `ClassLoader` only. You can dispose of it then make another to load the class again and invoke again.

It's a bit of work with reflection, and is certainly not a long-term solution, but yes you can isolate a class in this way by manipulating which `ClassLoader` holds it.

Comment: I like the classloader option, but using reflection is not an option for me. I need as much performance as I can get.

Comment: You wouldn't have a choice -- you have to make the call to the `Class` using reflection. That is, you cannot touch the class "directly" in your code. However, it's just the initial invocation that must proceed by reflection. Reflection really isn't that slow either. Certainly, if this is important code, you need to actually rewrite it properly instead of bandaging around it!